# Starting my android application automatically after connecting the USB cable.

Tags: android, usb

Is it possible me to start my android application if the user connecting USB cable to the device ?. I am going through the this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) . Am I in the correct path ?

Comment: are you trying to run the application on your device? USB debugging?

Comment: which android version you are going to use ?

Comment: I am trying to run the application in the device. my target version is 14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register an Receiver for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED in Manifest as:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnPowerReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and in Code part

```
public class OnPowerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Your_Activity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: android.intent.action.POWER_CONNECTED is it the correct one ?

Comment: yes i think it's correct for receiving USB cable plug-in or plug-out states but if you have any issue with it then you can go for USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.POWER_CONNECTED" />
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
I have used these two actions. it is not working but i am able to launch my applications with other actions like  <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />. SO it is not the problem with the code but the action i am using.

Comment: @Paru : sorry by mistake it's `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` not `android.intent.action.POWER_CONNECTED` so please change it and try it

Comment: I should have change that without posting it :-( It is working now. Thanks

Comment: It's not working for me when the app is force closed. Which is unfortunalty because the idea was to start the app even if a close it,

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it, you need to code for a `BroadcastReceiver` that will get fire when any event occurs at USB port ( plug-in or plug-out ).

```
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
```

when such things occurs, just fire an Intent to start your activity.

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.POWER_CONNECTED" /> <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> I have used these two actions. it is not working but i am able to launch my applications with other actions like <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />. SO it is not the problem with the code but the action i am using