# start my android app when usb connect

Tags: android, usb

I try to write app which can start when usb connect
I learn from [Starting my android application automatically after connecting the USB cable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445092/starting-my-android-application-automatically-after-connecting-the-usb-cable?answertab=active#tab-top)

my code is

```
    package com.example.formatsdcard;
    import java.io.File;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public class OnPowerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);   
        }   
    }   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mButton01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    mButton01.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    { 
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
          wipeMemoryCard();
      }
    });
```

MY Manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.formatsdcard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission   android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.formatsdcard.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".OnPowerReceiver">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
           </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
</application>
```

my app can run after I click it but it will show there're some problem try again later when I connect my usb cable.

How should I change my code to let it work normally.

Comment: `some problem try again later` care to elaborate ? logs ? exceptions ? stacktrace ? anything at all ?

Comment: is this your actual code ? if so, you need to move OnPowerReceiver out of MainActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try

```
<receiver android:name="MainActivity$OnPowerReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or try putting OnPowerReceiver as a public class in your package com.example.formatsdcard

Comment: Questions mentions about USB . Will this be triggered when charger is connected?

Comment: Does this get triggered even if the user closes the app by "Force Close" button?

Answer (score 0):

Create a own `class` for your `onPowerReceiver`. Don't put it in your MainActivity.